# Java Error: Cannot find symbol/Inventory Program

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and trying to compile this inventory program. I keep getting the same error message and can't figure out what I'm missing. The error is cannot find symbol and it is on lines 10,18,20,21,22,23 anyting that says Inventory has the ^ symbol pointing at them. I am enclosing what I have racked my brains and tried everything I can and would appreciate any help with this.

```
//InventoryProgram2.java
//Camera inventory program
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class InventoryProgram2
{
public static void main( String args [])
{
      //instantiate camera object
      Inventory myInventory = new Inventory();


      //displays welcome message
System.out.println( "Camera Invenotry Program");
System.out.println();//skips a line

//create and initialize an array of Cameras
Inventory[] Camera = new Inventory[4];

Camera[0] = new Inventory( 1980, "Cannon Rebel T3", 20, 489.99);
Camera[1] = new Inventory( 2120, "Nikon CoolPix L810", 5, 279.99);
Camera[2] = new Inventory( 1675, "Sony CyberShot HX200V", 12, 479.99);
Camera[3] = new Inventory( 1028, "Fujifilm FinePix S4300", 3, 199.99);

//for each array element, output value

for(int count = 0; count < Camera.length; count++)
{
    Camera[count] = count+1;

    System.out.printf("Product Number: %4.2f\n", Camera[count].getprodNumber() );
    System.out.printf("Product Name: %s\n", Camera[count].getprodName() );
    System.out.printf("Units In Stock: %.2f\n", Camera[count].getunitsTotal() );
    System.out.printf("Unit Price: $%4.2f\n", Camera[count].getunitPrice() );
    System.out.printf("Inventory Value: $%4.2f\n", Camera[0].gettotalInventory() );
    System.out.println();//blank line to seperate products

    }//end for 

}//end main method

}//end public class InventoryProgram2

class Camera
{

private int prodNumber;//product number
private String prodName;//product name
      private int unitsTotal;//total units in stock
      private double unitPrice;//price per unit
private double totalInventory;//amount of total inventory

//initializa four-argument constructor
public Camera ( int number, String name, int total, double price)
      {
     prodNumber = number;
     prodName = name;
     setUnitsTotal (total);//validate and store total of camera
     setUnitPrice (price);//validate and store price per camera

}//end four-argument constructor


public void setProdNumber (int number)
{
          prodNumber = number;
}

      public int getProdNumber()
{
    return prodNumber;
}

public void setProdName (String name)
{
    prodName = name;
}
      public String getProdName()
{
    return prodName;
}

public void setUnitsTotal (int total)
      {
    unitsTotal = total;
}
public int getUnitsTotal()
{
    return unitsTotal;
}  
      public void setUnitPrice (double price)
      {
    unitPrice = price;
}
      public double getUnitPrice()
{
    return unitPrice;
}


// method to set Inventory value
//public void setInventoryValue(double value)

//{
//InventoryValue = value;
//}end method setInventoryValue

//method to get InventoryValue
//public double getInventoryValue()
//{
// return InventoryValue;
//} //end method to getInventoryValue

public double getInventoryValue()
{
    return unitPrice * unitsTotal;
}//end method to getInventoryValue

//method to set TotalInventory
//public void setTotalInventory(double value)

//{
//TotalInventory = total;
//}end method setTotalInventory

//method to get TotalInventory
//public double getTotalInventory()

//{
//return TotalInventory;
//}end method to getTotalInventory

}//end class Camera
```

I needed to keep one class camera so I did some adjustemnts. I'm down to 7 errors as follows:

line 10: error: constructor Camera in class Camera cannot be applied to given types;
        Camera myCamera = new Camera();
    required: int,String,int,double
    found: no arguments
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

line 29: error: incompatible types
        Inventory[count] = count+1
                                ^
    required: Camera
    found: int

lines 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, : error cannot find symbol
        System.out.printf(......) [count].getprodNumber
                                         ^
    symbol: method getprodNumber()
    location: class Camera

here is my updated code:

```
//Inventory.java
```

//Camera inventory program
   import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class Inventory
{
public static void main( String args [])
      {
      //instantiate camera object
      Camera myCamera = new Camera();


//displays welcome message
System.out.println( "Camera Invenotry Program");
System.out.println();//skips a line

//create and initialize an array of Cameras
Camera[] Inventory = new Camera[4];

Inventory[0] = new Camera( 1980, "Cannon Rebel T3", 20, 489.99);
Inventory[1] = new Camera( 2120, "Nikon CoolPix L810", 5, 279.99);
Inventory[2] = new Camera( 1675, "Sony CyberShot HX200V", 12, 479.99);
Inventory[3] = new Camera( 1028, "Fujifilm FinePix S4300", 3, 199.99);

//for each array element, output value

for(int count = 0; count < Inventory.length; count++)
{
      Inventory[count] = count+1;

      System.out.printf("Product Number: %4.2f\n", Inventory[count] .getprodNumber() );
      System.out.printf("Product Name: %s\n", Inventory[count] .getprodName() );
      System.out.printf("Units In Stock: %.2f\n", Inventory[count] .getunitsTotal() );
      System.out.printf("Unit Price: $%4.2f\n", Inventory[count] .getunitPrice() );
      System.out.printf("Inventory Value: $%4.2f\n", Inventory[0] .gettotalInventory() );
      System.out.println();//blank line to seperate products

    }//end for 

}//end main method

}//end public class Inventory

class Camera
{

private int prodNumber;//product number
private String prodName;//product name
      private int unitsTotal;//total units in stock
      private double unitPrice;//price per unit
private double totalInventory;//amount of total inventory

//initializa four-argument constructor
public Camera ( int number, String name, int total, double price)
      {
     prodNumber = number;
     prodName = name;
     setUnitsTotal (total);//validate and store total of camera
     setUnitPrice (price);//validate and store price per camera

}//end four-argument constructor


public void setProdNumber (int number)
{
    prodNumber = number;
}

      public int getProdNumber()
{
    return prodNumber;
}

public void setProdName (String name)
{
    prodName = name;
}
      public String getProdName()
{
    return prodName;
}

public void setUnitsTotal (int total)
      {
    unitsTotal = total;
}
public int getUnitsTotal()
{
    return unitsTotal;
}  
      public void setUnitPrice (double price)
      {
    unitPrice = price;
}
      public double getUnitPrice()
{
    return unitPrice;
}


// method to set Inventory value
//public void setInventoryValue(double value)

//{
//InventoryValue = value;
//}end method setInventoryValue

//method to get InventoryValue
//public double getInventoryValue()
//{
// return InventoryValue;
//} //end method to getInventoryValue

public double getInventoryValue()
{
    return unitPrice * unitsTotal;
}//end method to getInventoryValue

//method to set TotalInventory
//public void setTotalInventory(double value)

//{
//TotalInventory = total;
//}end method setTotalInventory

//method to get TotalInventory
//public double getTotalInventory()

//{
//return TotalInventory;
//}end method to getTotalInventory

}//end class Camera
```

Comment: Where is the Inventory class? Perhaps it used to be Inventory but you renamed it ot InventoryProgram2?

Comment: I readjusted everything and posted new code and errors. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your Camera class should really be called Inventory.  You're using Camera in your main application class as a variable name not as a type.

Change `class Camera` to `class Inventory`

and

```
public Camera ( int number, String name, int total, double price)
```

to

```
public Inventory ( int number, String name, int total, double price)
```

and it should get you closer, if not all the way there.

Comment: I reposted the code to show my adjustments. Down to 7 errors. Any more help would br greatly appreciated.

Comment: Line 10 - you don't have a constructor for Camera that takes zero arguments.  Why do you feel you need myCamera?

Line 29 - the Inventory array holds Cameras, you're assigning it an integer.  That line isn't needed if you're just printing the contents.

Line 32++ - get rid of the space before the "." referencing your methods (I *think* space matters here, but not completely sure)

Comment: btw, your last reference in the print loop prints the value for Inventory[0] for each element of the array - did you want Inventory[count] there?

Comment: Changed around what you said. I deleted line 10 and 29. Now all I'm getting is the same error on the "." and I did get rid of the space.

Comment: ugh... just saw it.. subtle.  Java is case-sensitive.  Your Inventory class has methods like getUnitsTotal, but in lines 31+ you're invoking it as getunitsTotal.  The word after "get" isn't consistently capitalized.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for all the help. that got rid of all of the problems with the exception of the .getTotalInventory. Still showing cannot find symbol "." on just that line.

Comment: in the last code segment you posted, the getTotalInventory method is commented out

Comment: sorry I'm new to this and confused what exactly does that mean method is commented out?

Comment: any line prefaced by // is a comment, like "//displays welcome message" in the first few lines of your code.  Look to the bottom of the last code you posted, and you'll see you have code there but the lines all have // before them so are not compiled and treated as comments.

Comment: ok, thanks I got it. That cleared everything rxcept for 2 errors. on the bottom half in the camera class, the method to setInventoryValue is an issue. error reads cannot find symbol with ^ under the i in inventoryValue = value. same on that section with the "total" word in totalInventory = total

Comment: Think about setInventoryValue, what would it do?  Look at getInventoryValue, it computes something based on two other values # and cost, each of which you set independently.  The other fails because you set TotalInventory (capital T, should be small t) to the value of "total" which doesn't exist as a variable; you want "value" there since that's the parameter to the method.  Beyond that though you seem to have duplicate concepts. What is totalInventory vs. unitsTotal? is totalInventory the GRAND total? if so, is shouldn't be defined on your Camera class, since it applies at a higher level.

Comment: We are supposed to show the inventory value of each item then a total value for all of the types and inventories.

Comment: in general, don't store a value that you can calculate easily - the total inventory is the sum of all the getUnitPrice so calculate it in your print loop, don't store (and have to maintain) the identical value across all of the individual instances of camera.  BTW, what grade am I getting on this homework?

Comment: So far your getting an A+, hope mine turns out the same.

Comment: What I need to get out of the Inventoy value is to have the total inventory value of all 4 cameras.

Comment: so declare a local variable in your main method - like totalInventory, then in your for loop, you'll add the current Inventory[index].gotUnitsTotal to it... when the loop is done you have the value you want.

Comment: I feel like a real idiot right now. I've tried some stuff and still can't get it set properly in the main method.

Comment: ok, I got it to compile and run. The only thing I am missing is the total inventory value of all the cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `Inventory` class is in the same package as that of this class. Else just import that class like you did for `Arrays`.